# Not getting push notification alert using cordova plugins in phonegap developer app on android device

Tags: cordova, push-notification, cordova-plugins

We are trying to achieve push notifications in `cordova`.

For this we have studied a lot and found some solutions via cordova plugins.

To implement these solutions we have firstly:

- installed `cordova` then
- We have created a new cordova project
- Then, we have added android platform into that project.
- After this we have installed `plugman`
- Using plugman we have added [this](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) plugin with Sender_ID from google GCM.

Now, when we run the application in `Phonegap Developer App` we get `Device Ready` message. But we are not getting the notification alert.

**Any Help would be appreciated!**

**EDIT**

```
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},
// Bind Event Listeners
//
// Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
// 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
// deviceready Event Handler
//
// The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
// function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
},
// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
    pushNotification.register(app.successHandler, app.errorHandler,{"senderID":"693193766294","ecb":"app.onNotificationGCM"});
},
// result contains any message sent from the plugin call
successHandler: function(result) {
    alert('Callback Success! Result = '+result)
},
errorHandler:function(error) {
    alert(error);
},
onNotificationGCM: function(e) {
    switch( e.event )
    {
        case 'registered':
            if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
            {
                console.log("Regid " + e.regid);
                alert('registration id = '+e.regid);
            }
        break;

        case 'message':
          // this is the actual push notification. its format depends on the data model from the push server
          alert('message = '+e.message+' msgcnt = '+e.msgcnt);
        break;

        case 'error':
          alert('GCM error = '+e.msg);
        break;

        default:
          alert('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
          break;
    }
}    
};
```

This file is located here `RootDirectory/www/js/index.js`

Comment: Can you post code which is in your `deviceready` function ?

Comment: I have edit the question for your, please see the edit.

Comment: check after Create build and after installing in device. Not phonegap developer app.

Comment: Checked in `phonegap developer app, and checked `after building .apk` as well`.

Comment: After all this, we are getting alert message with `Class Not Found`

Comment: which class is missing ? i guess `pushNotification`

Comment: Yes you're right.!
But we have added pushNotification.js which we have found in plugin. 
Plugin Name `com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin`

Comment: Check in documentation wether you have to manually include `js` file for that class to be found !!

Comment: can you try with this plugin instead ? https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin and do not use plugman this time

Comment: We have already added `pushNotification.js` file from plugin directory to `RootDirectory/www` as specified in documentation. We are referring this guide `http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/`

Comment: It is possible that `www` directory in platform folder is not getting that file.

Comment: We have created the project using command line. And we are on Windows
We don't have any`www` directory in platform folder, we have only 2 directories in platform folder 1 is `android` and the other is `browser`
But we do have `platform_www` under RootDirectory/platforms/android/platform_www

Comment: `platform/android/www` ?

Comment: We don't have only `www` but we have `platform_www` under `platform/android/`

Comment: OK is that having plugin's js file ?

Comment: My platform_www folder looks like this:
cordova-js-src (folder),
plugins (folder),
cordova.js,
cordova_plugins.js

Comment: Does `platform_www` folder's index.html file contains same code as its in root `www` folder ?